# Does anyone know how to convert a datefield to a string in java j2me?

Tags: java, java-me

I need to get the data from a datefield calender and be able to display it in a string and later store it in a recordstore. I tried the toString() method but i had an error once run.

```
        StartDate = new DateField("Start Date ", DateField.DATE);
        StartDate.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

I now have this code

```
     public static String dateToString (long date)
    {

     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance() ;

     c.setTime(new Date(date));
     int y = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     int m = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; 
     int d = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
     String t = (y<10? "0": "")+y+"-"+(m<10? "0": "")+m+"-"+(d<10?
     "0": "")+d;
     return t;  
      }
```

How can I change this in order for this to get the date from Startdate and make that t.?

If anyone could help!

Comment: what was the error when you ran toString() ?

Comment: the came up on the emilator saying javax.microedition.icdui.datefield@1cb37664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some [sample implementations](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t126578-p2-convert-date-to-string-with-j2me.html) that may help you get started, since it appears your runtime doesn't provide a useful `toString` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/date-string.shtml) solve your problem?

> ```
> ...
>   date = new Date();
>   currentDate = new DateField("", DateField.DATE_TIME);
>   currentDate.setDate(date);
>   dateinstring = date.toString();
>   System.out.println("Date And Time Is In String Format: "+dateinstring);
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this

```
...
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance() ;

   c.setTime(new Date(date));
   int y = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   int m = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; 
   int d = c.get(Calendar.DATE);

   Date t = c.getTime();
   String str = t.format("YY-MM-dd");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change the parameter type of dateToString to Date:
Public static String dateToString(Date date)

Then after
StartDate.setDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
add this line:
String dateString = dateToString(StartDate.getDate());

Well, at least that works in my MIDlet.
Hopefully this helps.

Regards,

wahyu a

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna use this:

> public String getDateFormat(Date inDate){

```
String stDate = null;
String dd = null;
String mm = null;
String yyyy = null;
Calendar cd = Calendar.getInstance();
cd.setTime(inputDT);
int iD = cd.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH );
if (iD < 10){ dd = "0" + String.valueOf(iD); }
    else { dd = String.valueOf(iD); }
int iM = cd.get( Calendar.MONTH )+1;
    if (iM < 10){ mm = "0" + String.valueOf(iM); }
    else { mm = String.valueOf(iM); }
int iY = cd.get( Calendar.YEAR );
    yyyy = String.valueOf(iY);
stDate = yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd;
return stDate;
```

> }

to get the 'long' variable become 'Date' use the Date(long date) from java.util.Date}